# Android Load WebView and Javascript

Tags: javascript, android

I am writing an app using WebView to load my html, css, js and get some problems when loading the html.

Here is the MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    HTMLDataBase myDB1;
    ContentTableDataBase myDB2;
    CloudTableDataBase myDB3;
    InterviewDataBase myDB4;
    Context context;
    boolean check;

    private WebView view;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myDB1 = new HTMLDataBase(this);
        myDB2 = new ContentTableDataBase(this);
        myDB3 = new CloudTableDataBase(this); 
        myDB4 = new InterviewDataBase(this); 

        display_html();
        Javascript_Android_Communication();

    }

    public void display_html()
    {
        WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


        Cursor res = myDB1.getAllData();

        if (res.getCount() > 0) {
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while (res.moveToNext())
            {
                buffer.append(res.getString(0) + ",");
                buffer.append(res.getString(1) + ",");
                buffer.append(res.getString(2) + ",");
            }
            
            String[] result = buffer.toString().substring(0, buffer.toString().trim().length() - 1).split(",", -2);

            if (result[2].equals("block"))
            {
                view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
            }

            if (!result[2].equals("block"))
            {
                view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index2.html"); // Problem occurs when loading this html
            };
        }

    }

    public void Javascript_Android_Communication()
    {
        WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);
        view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {});
        WebSettings settings = view.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        view.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
        view.addJavascriptInterface(new WebViewJavaScriptInterface(this), "app");
    }
}
```

Javascript requests information from DataBase and imports them to:

```
document.getElementById("").style.display = "";
```

The problem is data can be extracted but the html is never completely loaded and thus errors occurs when I change the html element. When I open the logcat, it said "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null".

Whenever I use alert method to call

```
document.getElementById("").style.display
```

It simply returns me empty.

I try to use

```
document.addEventListener("load",function(){alert(document.getElementById().style.display);});
```

but the page is never completely loaded so it just wastes my time. What shall I do so that I can change the html with data I have extracted.

Comment: `document.getElementById("")` isn’t going to work. What is your intention with `document.getElementById("").style.display = "";`?

Comment: Well, I want to change the display of element but it doesn't allow me to do so. When I check "document.getElementById("")==null", it return true. But I am quite sure my element does exist.

Comment: "Well, I want to change the display of element" - Very well, but *which* element? You're not using any ID to specify the element which should have its style changed.

Comment: Well, of course I do specify the element I want to change when writing the script. The problem is the javascript is very complicated that I cannot display them all. It is just the format I use to change the html element.